# python : generate sublists depending on the elements values

Tags: python, sublist

I have a list of elements, and I want to generate an arbitrary number of sub-lists from that list. All the elements of a given sub-list must have the same output from a function `f`.

For example :

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6] # my list to split into sublist
>>> sublists = list() # my sublists
>>> def f(e) : # the function used to discriminate the elements
...  return e%2
... 
>>> for ret in [0,1] :
...   sublists.append([e for e in mylist if f(e) == ret])
... 
>>> print(sublists)
[[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
```

This works great, but only because I know exactly which values `f` can return: `0`, or `1`. So I can iterate on these output values and then create the sub-lists.

But what if I don't know beforehand the values that `f` can `return`? Is there a good Pythonic way to do it? I would like to avoid having to iterate over `mylist` just to see what `f` can output on all the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)
for e in mylist:
    out[f(e)].append(e)
```

Now as long as `f(e)` is hashable for all appropriate values of `e`, you will get an output like

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [2, 4, 6], 1: [1, 3, 5]})
```

If you want a list of these sub-lists, you can then do:

```
sublists = list(out.values())
```

However note that dictionaries aren't guaranteed to retain a sensible order; each sublist will remain ordered, but you could get

```
[[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
```

or

```
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

in this example.

---

The long-form equivalent to show what `defaultdict` does:

```
out = {}
for e in mylist:
    key = f(e)
    if key not in out:
        out[key] = []
    out[key].append(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for diversity:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
f = lambda x: x % 2

zipt = sorted((f(x), x) for x in mylist)

for x, y in groupby(zipt, key=itemgetter(0)):
    print(x, [z[1] for z in y])
```

prints

```
0 [2, 4, 6]
1 [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah but it's also very readable, not that `defaultdict` isn't. Gotta love `itertools`. What can't it do?

Comment: @wheaties I'm a big fan of `itertools`, don't get me wrong!